# Updates the data in vue with laravel without refreshing the page or overlapping the div

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem in sight.
I just started to learn, but I'm confused about something, why when I update the data I send with axios.post and update them, the devil disappears for 2 seconds and refreshes the page.
Look how I thought

```
<li v-for="question in questions" :key="question.id" class="list-group-item">
            {{ question.questiontype }}
        <br>
        <button v-on:click="addVote(question.id)">Add 1</button>
        <br>
        <span class="badge badge-primary"><strong>{{ question.votes }}</strong></span>
        </li>
data() {
            return {
              success: false,
              questions:[],
              percentages:[],
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getQuestions(),
            this.getPercentages()
        },
        methods: {
            getQuestions(){
                axios.get('/api/questionlist')
                    .then((response)=>{
                       this.questions = response.data.question
                    })
            },
            getPercentages(){
                axios.get('/api/getpercentage')
                    .then((response)=>{
                       this.percentages = response.data.percentage
                    })
            },
            addVote(id) {
               axios.post('api/vote/' + id)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.questions = response.data.question
                        console.log(response.data)
                        this.getQuestions()
                    })
            }
```

So I'm interested in the data I sent with the post.
I would like the page to update without refresh or to overlap the div for 2 seconds.
What exactly am I doing wrong?
I tried a few ways on stackoverflow but they didn't help

Comment: In your response you have `this.questions = response.data.question` which I assume sets the value of your `questions` array, but then you do `this.getQuestions()` two lines after which will overwrite them so you'll be updating your compoent twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `button` is inside a form, you probably want to add `type="button"` attribute to it or prevent the form submission action.

```html
<button type="button" v-on:click="addVote(question.id)">Add 1</button>
```

OR:

```html
<button v-on:click.prevent="addVote(question.id)">Add 1</button>
```

I'm guessing that's probably why you're seeing the page refresh. If you want to display the updated data, you either need to make another axios call to fetch or you need to return the new entry from your API endpoint and push/add it to your list.

So modify your code as follows:

```js
addVote(id) {
   axios.post('api/vote/' + id)
        .then((response) => this.getQuestions());
}
```

Comment: And yet I will not use that answer again?
For example:
this.questions = response.data.question?
Or something